# Algorithm to find a rational number between i and j, minimizing for number of significant figures after n iterations

Tags: algorithms, number-systems

I have a program where, a user selects a number $i$ from a list of floats, and the program adds a number k to the list such that $i < k < j$ where $j$ is the upper neighbour of $i$ in the list (if $j$ doesn't exist set $j = i+1$).

Our data may start with the list $\{1, 2, 3\}$.

One approach is for $k$ to be the midpoint of $i$ and $j$, in which case when the user selects $2$, the program adds $(2+3)/2 = 2.5$ to the list, so we have $\{1, 2, 2.5, 3\}$.

Then the user may again select $2$, which would add $(2+2.5)/2 = 2.25$ to the list and so on.

This works, but my limitation is the number of significant figures in my float.

I noticed that in Base 8, given the number $2$,

$\frac{(2+3)}{2} = \frac{5}{2} = 2.4$,

then given the number 2 again,

$\frac{2+2.4}{2} = \frac{4.4}{2} = 2.2$, and

given the number 2 again,

$\frac{2+2.2}{2} = \frac{4.2}{2} = 2.1$.

This means that over 3 iterations of the program, we are only using 2 s.f.

In fact, given any selections over 3 iterations, we are guaranteed to have no number of more than 2 s.f. in our list.

However in base 10, the result after 3 iterations on the number 2 would be $2.125$ which has 4 s.f.

Restricting ourselves to base 10 and the starting list $\{1, 2, 3\}$, what is an algorithm on $i$ and $j$ such that given any user selections, we ensure that after 3 iterations there are no entries with 3 or more s.f.? Bonus if the algorithm is not conditional on the values of $i$ and $j$.

Comment: At the nth step, your list of numbers will be of the form $ a/ 2^n$. So yes, using base $2^m$ will allow you to maintain the accuracy and not need that many sf/dp. $\quad$ In fact, why stop at base 8, where over 4 iterations you need 3sf? if you use base 512, then you'd only need 3sf at 11 iterations. The obvious tradeoff is the complexity of storing the digits, which you have not addressed. $\quad$ Taking a stab without knowing much more, my recommendation would be to use base 2, and at the nth iteration allow for n decimal places.

Comment: @CalvinLin I am restricted to base 10 only

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stern%E2%80%93Brocot_tree

Comment: Restricting to base 10, you don't have much hope of reducing the number of sf that's involved.  Like you could start out with "multiples of powers of 2", but eventually you'd have to add ~1 sig fig each time, because you are dividing by 2 (and 2 only divides 10 once). Whereas in base 8, you add ~1/3 sig fig each time.

Comment: My train of thought is that the base 8 system contains strictly less information than base 10, and works quite elegantly with 2, so I was wondering if there is an equally elegant way to achieve this efficiency in base 10.